# Metric Space - A point outside unit ball in $l^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and inside unit ball in $l^\infty (\mathbb R^2)$.

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> A point outside unit ball in $l^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and inside unit ball in $l^\infty (\mathbb R^2)$. Is there a $p$ between 1 and infinity such that $||x||_p = 1$? How about in $\mathbb R^n?$

Since it is outside the unit ball in $l^1(\mathbb R^2)$ and inside the unit ball in $l^\infty (\mathbb R^2)$, $l^1$ norm is $\geq 1$ and $l^\infty$ norm is $\leq 1$. But I am not sure how to approach this question. How do I get started?

Answer (score 1):

The unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$-norm is the square whose vertices are $(\pm1,0)$ and  $(0,\pm1)$, whereas the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$-norm is the square whose vertices are the numbers of the form $(\pm1,\pm1)$. So take, for instance, the point $(a,a)$, with $a\in\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right)$.

Comment: I am still confused with $||x||_p = 1$ part. are we able to find p between 1 and $\infty$ such that $||x||_p = 1$ always holds?

Comment: If $a\in(0,1)$, then$$\bigl\lVert(a,a)\bigr\rVert=a\bigl\lVert(1,1)\bigr\rVert=a2^{\frac1p}.$$So, choose $p$ such that $a2^{\frac1p}=1$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. What if the point lies on (a, b), a, b $\in \left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right)$, a $\neq$ b. Or is this same thing as $(a^p + b^p)^\frac{1}{p} = 1 \Rightarrow$ choose p such that $a^p + b^p = 1$?.

Comment: I just looked for the simplest solution, but there are others, of course.

Comment: Does this hold true for $\mathbb R^n$ as well?

Comment: Yes, it holds true there too.